# Application icon background at google play store is not transparent

Tags: android

I have set my new app icon on google play store and the white parts of my app doesnt

get the color of the background like in other appliction apps.

I post here images to show what i mean:

Thank for helping.

[image]

Comment: did you make your image with a transparent background?

Comment: how do you i make it on PNG files?

Comment: open your browser to google and type "How you make PNG with transparent background"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a transparent one using a photo editor and save it as png. JPG can't handle transparency and eventually saves the file with white areas.

Comment: Ok, do you have guide for this?

Comment: You can use gimp (www.gimp.org) which is free and do something like this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6449/add-transparency-to-an-existing-png

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a .PNG image or JPGE? You should use a PNG image with transparent area.

Comment: I needed to set the background transpred